# How to make a directory hidden without dot at the beginning of directory on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, unix, boost

I want to make a directory hidden on Mac OSX without using dot at the beginning of directory as the directory should be cross platform. So is there any extended attribute which can be set to make the cross platform directory hidden? I tried the bellow sample code where it is making a directory hidden but if i copy the same directory to any other different system it is not show as hidden. Any pointer please?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  mode_t permission;
  permission = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH;

  if(mkdir("./dir_test", permission) != 0)
  {
      std::cout<<"Failed to create directory"<<std::endl;
      return -1;
  }

  u_int flags;
  flags = UF_HIDDEN;

  if(chflags("./dir_test", flags) != 0)
      std::cout<<"Failed to set attr\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The concept of a "hidden directory" (or file) is not cross-platform, so no, there's nothing you can do here. The display (or failure to display_ of a file in a directory list is managed not by the operating system, but by the tool itself. The operating system tells the requester that the file is there, and the tool decides to show it to the user or not.

Comment: there is little that portable cross platform, but suggest reading the following link, for ways to hide a file on the mac os.

http://www.macworld.com/article/2030765/8-ways-to-hide-files-and-folders-in-os-x.html

This link describes several methods for hiding files in the max os.

(it is way too long to copy/paste here and it does include a video)

Comment: You can use [chflags(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html), [chflags(2), or fchflags(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chflags.2.html) to set the UF_HIDDEN flag for a directory, but as @mah said, this flag is unlikely to have any effect on other platforms.

Comment: @GordonDavisson i had tired with chflags function/chflags command it make the directory hidden but when i do copy that directory to any other system Mac / Windows system it does not keep as hidden. Is there any way to make the directory hidden permanently? Just wondering setting kind of file attribute might help?

Comment: I have checked if we hide a directory in windows that is also becoming hidden in Mac OSX. But how can i make it happen from OSX?